# What is the type of a DataGrid control?

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I need to send different DataGrid control object references to a function. Something like this is possible with many controls like a Form:

```
Dim lForm as Form
Set lForm = frmPrint

MsgBox(lForm.Caption)
```

But so far it has not been possible to do this with DataGrid control **because it results in a "`type mismatch`" error.**

```
Dim lGrid as ?  '( I tried DataGrid and Object here but not possible)
set lGrid = myDataGrid

Call myFunc(lGrid) 
.
.
.

Private Sub myFunc(ByRef pMyGrid as ?)

   MsgBox pMyGrid.Caption

End Sub
```

It is possible with MSFlexGrid control as well, but I need to use DataGrid control.

Thanks

Comment: `DataGrid` should work fine.  What was your issue?

Comment: `Dim lGrid As MSDataGridLib.DataGrid`?

Comment: It works if I use MSDataGridLib.DataGrid. Thanks @jac

Comment: you might have two different classes called DataGrid in your project - that could be why the full name MSDataGridLib.DataGrid is needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, how can I fix it so?